# Is it possible to override a custom TagHelper without modifying the _ViewImports.cshtml file?

Tags: asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm creating a plugin for a website that uses a custom TagHelper, let's call it MainTagHelper.

I would like to override the MainTagHelper from my plugin, lets call it PluginTagHelper, which is in a different namespace. I can do this if I update the main website _ViewImports.cshtml file by adding a reference to my plugin via the @addTagHelper razor command. I would like to avoid that since my plugin won't have access to that file in a production setting.

I've tried using the MainTagHelper as a base class for my PluginTagHelper but it never gets called. I assuming this is because the main _ViewImports.cshtml is calling the MainTagHelper directly.

Any thoughts on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Tag helpers cannot be overridden. All registered tag helpers are applied in the order in which they are registered (such as in `_ViewImports.cshtml`).